# What is scala.enable file?

Tags: scala, maven, pom.xml

I have a java maven project and now I have to include codebase in scala for that project. I added the scala dependencies to pom.xml. As soon as I create the directory src/main/scala, my project build starts to fail with the following error.

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-scala-enable-exist) on project XYZ.

Some required files are missing - projectpath/scala.enable.

I have done such integrations in the past but never faced an issue like this. I could not find any information on scala.enable file. As soon as I add scala.enable file, I am successfully able to build the project. I also get it that it is to enable scala in the project but as far as my understanding goes it should happen on it's own and I don't need to push such files to production. I want to understand if I can avoid adding scala.enable file to the project.

Answer (score 0):

It was enforced at parent pom level in my case. So there are two ways you can bypass this. remove the parent pom.xml if you can. or you can override this setting in your project pom.xml using below snippet.

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>enforce-scala-enable-exist</id>
    <goals>
    <goal>enforce</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration combine.self="override">
    <rules>
    <requireFilesExist>
    <files>
    <file>${project.build.directory}/scala.enable</file>
    </files>
    </requireFilesExist>
    </rules>
    <fail>false</fail>
    </configuration>
    </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
```